# Bootstrap 3 - Element Divs in Row not cascading correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Problem**
I am using Bootstrap 3 in a SharePoint Environment. When I view the screen on the computer, everything looks good and clean as it should. It scales and adjusts appropriately. However, when I scale down to the phone size, I then have an unexpected situation. Div 1 and 2 disappear in a particular section of the page. Now, this does not happen in the other portions of the page, because the first div in the row is a col-xs-12, whereas in the code below, you can see that it is the final div.

**HTML Code**

```
<!-- Paralegal -->
<div class="row cafManager bhiOutlinedRow" id="Paralegal">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 bhiCAFLabel">
        <span class="bhiCafTitleHighlight">Paralegal </span>
        <br />
        <p class="bhiCafApprover">
            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff27{$Pos}" ControlMode="Display" FieldName="Paralegal" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff27',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Paralegal')}"/>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-2 bhiCAFLabel">
        <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff280{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="Paralegal_x0020_Approval" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff28',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Paralegal_x0020_Approval')}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-md-7">
        <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff29{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="Paralegal_x0020_Comments" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff29',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Paralegal_x0020_Comments')}"/>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End Paralegal  -->
```

**Visuals**
Div Layout Image: http://screencast.com/t/BUbFAD6JhY

This is what it is showing for a smaller screen:
http://screencast.com/t/wmP6JPvV

**Attempted Solutions**
Now, I have gone onto Twitter Bootstrap, and I attempted a number of tweaks and fixes such as this:

getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets

However, that only puts a clear between the elements even in the full version (full size screen), and so, disrupts the rest of the view.

Second, I did try doing **row-fluid** however that ended up breaking the entire design in more than just the fields lining up poorly (divs were stacking on top of each other and ignoring all styling).

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I need to have this working for Mobile as well as for the Desktop.

**Additional Information**

The following Edit is being added to show the code for the section that does work.

```
<div class="row bhiOutlinedRow cafFullKeyContractClauses" data-contract-clause-operational="true">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 bhiCAFLabel"><span class="bhiFormLabel">Factory Audits: </span></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
        <div id="Factory_x0020_Audits" class="cafElement"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
        <div id="Factory_x0020_Audits_x0020_Descr" class="cafElement"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What I have know that total count of columns should be 12

Comment: Can you tell us more about your custom css, e.g. `bhiCAFLabel`? I wonder if there are definitions that break your layout.

Comment: @Pranavadurai It was my understanding that if the column size was greater than 12, that it would cascade into a new line. This works in other parts of the form, which is why I was confused on that.

Comment: @timo.rieber the bhiCAFLabel is just a background coloration label. Bascially, it is to fake a 2 column setting, even though it is really 3 (for design reasons this programmer doesn't know) :)

Comment: Ok, I don't like the solution I am doing for this, however, because of time, I am switching the items to **col-xs-12**. It doesn't look bad, but it is not how I had envisioned it. Thank you everyone for your help.